# Applying for UK visit visit myself and my daughter. Do I need to supply duplicate supporting documents?

Tags: paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, children

I am applying for a UK visit visa for myself and my 6 year old. Can I submit 1 set of supporting documents or will we need to duplicate this for both applications?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to supply the multiple copies. This is clearly stated in the Supporting Documents Guide Section 4.

> If you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide multiple copies of the same documents

The important this is that you provide the GWF of yourself & your 6-year-old in the remarks section in both the applications.