# Applying for UK Visa for honeymoon trip

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

I am currently employed in India and intend to travel to London followed by Schengan countries on honeymoon with my future wife.

In case of applying for UK visa, what should both of us mention on our application for civil/marital status? Since we are unmarried at the time of applying, should we mention "unmarried" or since we will be travelling as married couple, should we mention "married"?

Secondly, in case of applying for my future wife, can we mention on the cover letter that I shall be funding her trip and bearing all her expenses during the entire trip? In this case, are her bank account statements required, or can we include only my statements?

Comment: I was inspired to edit this question because "would be" is frequently used in connection with an unrealistic or vain desire, or for someone who is already pretending to be something, falsely.  That is presumably not the case here!  While I was in the editor, I decided to do some additional cleanup.  Of course of you disagree with any of it, you should edit it again.

Answer (score 4):

Q1 Enter your marital status as at the application date. You can make your wedding plans clear in the ‘additional information’ section at the end of the application, and in your covering letter [What details should a good cover letter contain to back up a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli)

Q2 The application contains a section where the applicant explains who is paying or contributing to the costs of the trip. You can include in your cover letter any information about your role as financial sponsor that’s not already clear in the application.

Q3 Your future wife should provide her bank statements. [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) Make sure you quote your GWF application reference in her application and the cover letter. You don’t need to duplicate documents when applying together [Applying for UK visit visit myself and my daughter. Do I need to supply duplicate supporting documents?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121523/applying-for-uk-visit-visit-myself-and-my-daughter-do-i-need-to-supply-duplicat)

Since the U.K. is your first entry point, they’ll prefer to see evidence that you have the right documents to enter your next destination. Ideally therefore, if you don’t already have valid Schengen visas, you should apply for those first and then the U.K. visas [Visa application for a multidestination trip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152312/visa-application-for-a-multidestination-trip)